# How to Count the Items that Occur a Certain Number of Times in a List

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to simplify a task that requires counting of values that occur 3 or more times in a list and then simply making a list of these values in a column as can be seen in the image. I would be glad if someone can show me the way to do it. thanks!!

[image]

Comment: That could be easily done with a Pivot Table. However, the Pivot Table will show the counting of every number in your data. You will have to manually filter the values that occur 3 or more times. Or you want to do it using formulas?

Comment: I don't prefer using the pivot table, it won't do the job for me. I would like to use formulas, I tried to do it myself but couldn't figure it out. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part is to find an array with the list, without the duplicate values. To find this, we use the following formula (array formula, Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$20),0))
```

The COUNTIF() function returns an array with either 0 or 1 provided they found the contents of $B$1:B1 in $A$2:$A$20 (the $ is important for absolute and relative references, since you will copy this formula to other cells).

The MATCH() function returns the relative position of an item that matches 0. With the COUNTIF() function, we put 0 to every member not found in the list. It returns the first occurrence of every number on the list.

The INDEX() function returns the list $A$2:$A$20 without duplicates (we have the first occurrence of every item in the MATCH() function).

After finding this list, we use again the COUNTIF() function to count how many occurrences of each item we have on the list (since you are looking for >=3 occurrences). To simplify the formulas, say you name the array given by the previous formula `list`. So, the counting is performed:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,list)
```

Then we check which count is bigger than 3 and return the correspondent value, if it is, or a blank, if it is not:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,list)>=3,list,"")
```

Don't forget it is an array formula, so type it and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Notice this last formula is just like the first one, but the list given by the INDEX() function is named `list`. You can define a Name by going to Formulas -> Defined Names -> Define Name. Excel displays the New Name dialog box. Call ir `list` or whatever and type in the INDEX() formula. It is clearer too read and easier to understand the formula using the name, but is not necessary.

The list without repetitions must be on Column B and the IF() function on Column C. The results should look like that (you can hide column B):

[image]